# how to implement search function by connecting two components in angular 2?

Tags: angular, components

I'm new in angular and i need to implement search function in my app. i have two components; one of them is the navbar(admin-layout component) and the other is incoming_mails; i have an input in my navbar and a datatable in incoming_mails component. when i type something in the navbar the datatable rows must change based on the input value. how can i do it?
here is some of my admin-layout component.ts:

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'app-layout',
  templateUrl: './admin-layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-layout.component.scss']
})
export class AdminLayoutComponent implements OnInit {


  private _router: Subscription;

  rows = [];
  temp = [];
  constructor(private router: Router, private snackBar: MdSnackBarprivate mailService: MailService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.mailService.getIncoming().subscribe(mails => {
      if(!mails.success){
        this.snackBar.open(mails.message, '', {
          duration: 2000,
          extraClasses: ['error-snackbar']
        });
      } else {
        const data = mails.mails.rows;
        // console.log(data)
        this.rows = data;
        this.temp = [...data];
      }
    });
  }

  updateFilter(event){
    // ????
  }
```

and this is part of incoming_mail component:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.mailService.getIncomingMails().subscribe(mails => {
  if(!mails.success){
    this.snackBar.open(mails.message, '', {
      duration: 2000,
      extraClasses: ['error-snackbar']
    });
  } else {
    const data = mails.mails.rows;
    this.rows = data;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is with communicating between components, you have two options into sending your filterText from navbar to mail component and from there filter the table

## Option 1

You could use a shared service and make use of BehaviorSubject from 'rxjs'

```
//mail.service.ts

import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

filterValue:BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('');


//admin-layout.component.ts

updateFilter(input_val) {
    this.mailService.filterValue.next(input_val)
}

//incoming_mail.component.ts

filterValue = ''

ngOnInit() {
    //Your code
    this.mailService.filterValue.subscribe(val => {
    this.filterValue = val
 })
}
```

## Option 2

You could use Output and EventEmitter to show you a small example

```
import { Output, Input, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';


//admin-layout.component.ts

@Output()
filterValue: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

updateFilter(input_val) {
    this.filterValue.emit(input_val)
}

//incoming_mail.component.ts

@Input()
filterValue:string;

ngOnChanges(changes) {
   //render your table 
}

//parent.template.html

<app-layout (filterValue)="onFilterValue($event)"></app-layout>
<app-incoming-mails [filterValue]="filterValue"></app-incoming-mails>

//parent.component.ts

filterValue:string = '';

onFilterValue(val) {
    this.filterValue = val;
}
```

With this you will Output the value of the input from admin-layout to the parent component, lets assume is app.component.ts, then you will save the filterValue into the variable that serves as Input for incoming-mails component, which then will trigger ngOnChanges from incoming-mails since the Input val has changed.

If your matter is on filtering the table I would suggest taking a look over [this](https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2017/03/16/angular2-creating-custom-search-filter-pipe-for-ngfor-directive/)